# Output buffering not working as expected?

Tags: php, output-buffering

I have a long-running script and want to use output buffering to send output to the browser periodically.

I'm confused, because I've read a number of questions on here that said to use this:

```
while (...) {
    ob_start();
    // echo statements
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

But that didn't work for me. I also tried this:

```
while (...) {
    ob_start();
    // echo statements
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

But that didn't work either. The only thing that seems to work is this:

```
while (...) {
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();
    // echo statements
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

Why do I have to call `ob_end_clean()` first in order for output buffering to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it depends on the rest of your code.

For me the following code works without a problem:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
$x = 1;

while ($x < 10) {
    echo $x."<br />";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
    ++$x;
}
```

You can use `ob_implicit_flush()` but it makes you don't need to run `flash()` each time you run `ob_flush()` so above code can be changed to:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
$x = 1;

ob_implicit_flush(true);

while ($x < 10) {
    echo $x."<br />";
    ob_flush();    
    sleep(1);
    ++$x;
}
```

You should also look at your `header()`. If in any of above codes I remove/comment line with header all the content will be displayed after scripts ends execution. Output buffering won't work as expected

Comment: I didn't have a header() statement and I think that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You do it the wrong way. This will do it:

```
while (...) {
    // echo statements
    flush();
}
```

Make sure, your Webserver is configured to delegate the Output without own cache. Output Buffer `ob_start` is only needed, if you want to get the output later as string.

Also take a look at [`ob_implicit_flush`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.ob-implicit-flush.php), which will automaticly perform a flush on output.